# Ubuntu 12.04 and Hyper-V 2008 R2 SCVMM - Network cable unplugged

Tags: networking, hyper-v

After attempting to install Ubuntu Desktop 32bit on our HyperV environment - which requires static IP addressing, Ubuntu thinks the network cable is unplugged.  It's connected to the correct Team NIC in SCVMM (like 40 or so other servers; which are all working fine) but for some reason it doesn't detect that the cable is "plugged in".
I'm going to try Ubuntu Server 64-bit to see if that works.

UPDATE -
looks like server has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. However, I tried to install 12.04 server 32-bit and that worked with no problem. It seems, for me anyway, that this is an issue with the 64-bit version. 
I'm running the stand alone Hyper-V 2008 server on an HP Proliant DL360 Gen8.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where the eth0 was showing lots of errors and dropped packets. I double checked the SCVMM Virtual Machine Properties and Network Adapter 1 was of the "Emulated" type. Once I set it to "Synthetic" (supported via hv_netvsc module compiled into Kernel 3.1) I was in business. I'm guessing that this is SCVMM's default when you select "Other Linux (64 bit)" during initial creation of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

edited:

I solve it [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286173/ubuntu-on-13-04-hyper-v-connection-problem)

Just delete the bridge connection ( between your real NIC and your virtual vEthernt (of Hyper-v)) Share internet connection like in the link below and it will work.
https://superuser.com/questions/489746/ubuntu-not-connecting-to-network-in-hyper-v

Answer (score 0):

In our case helped: unchecked "enable virtual machine queue" and disable ipsec (both in hardware acceleration section of network card).