# ubuntu on 14.04 hyper-v connection problem

Tags: 13.04, networking, virtualization, hyper-v

I recently download the new disk of 13.04 of 32bit.
I have Hyper-v on windows 8 64bit.
I try to operate 13.04 on hyper-v but I can't connect to the network.
I have already set at hyper-v manager that will create my wifi connection to network.
It work at windows 7 and 12.04 inside the Hyper-v, so I know the setting I set for vm is right.

How I can also operate network at 13.04?
I try already with legacy and non legacy network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete the bridge connection ( between your real NIC and your virtual vEthernt (of Hyper-v))
Share internet connection like in the link below and it will work. https://superuser.com/questions/489746/ubuntu-not-connecting-to-network-in-hyper-v